# Questions about refs callback in reactjs (ES6 vs non ES6)

Tags: reactjs, callback

So I'm reading the literature described here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

And I understand refs in general in how you can use it to access the DOM. But when it talked about callbacks, I got really confused.

To summarize it says (I'm paraphrasing here) that the "callback function gets called when the component is mounted.. it uses the referenced component to be passed into the parameter of the callback in render". I'm sorely confused by this.

So in their example:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <TextInput
            ref={function(input) {
                if (input != null) {
                    input.focus();
                }
           }} />
    );
},
```

So what is the value of "input" when it gets called. Is it the react component of:

```
<TextInput />
```

Which I'm also assuming is really a wrapper for:

```
<input type="text" />
```

otherwise focus() wouldn't work right?

And my next question is, does ComponentDidMount lifecycle execute before the callback mentioned in the ref in the render lifecycle or after?

because then I see this example (which looks completely different than the non-es6 standard.. it threw me off)

```
render: function() {
    return <TextInput ref={(c) => this._input = c} />;
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    this._input.focus();
},
```

which is saying that if you're not using ES6, the logic (namely input.focus()) will be found in the callback found in the render lifecycle. But if you're using ES6, you're moving that logic to componentDidMount lifecycle.

So I'm thinking with the ES6 standard, the callback gets called first, to set the referenced component (I'm assuming is TextInput), as a new alias called "_input", which is recognized and used later in componentDidMount, even though it wasn't declared anywhere else.

Am I right in any of this?

And one more question, if I'm using nonES6 standards, how would I accomplish the same task of having componentDidMount do the logic described in ES6 example? like if I was to do this..

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <TextInput
            ref={function(c) {
                this._input = c;
           }} />
    );
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    this._input.focus();
},
```

or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example to work, you will need to [bind `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to the `ref`-callback as `React.createClass` automatically binds `this` to the props, but not the callback functions.

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <TextInput
            ref={function(c) {
                this._input = c;
           }.bind(this)} />
    );
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    this._input.focus();
},
```

Otherwise `this` inside the `ref` is `undefined`

```
<TextInput
   ref={function(c) {
     console.log(this); // undefined
     this._input = c;
 }} />
```

In the ES6 example the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) handles the lexical binding of `this` for you.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56Lxhhjx/)

Comment: wow that actually makes sense.. also can you explain the lifecycles as well, do callbacks happen before componentDidMount? Or after? The literature says that it happens after a component is mounted. And is the value of "c" the react component TextInput?

Comment: @sksallaj the ref-callback happens after the component has been mounted. As `c` in the refers to the mounted node (since 0.14) itself, `this._input` is `undefined` until that time. You can test it out by `console.log`:in `this._input` during `componentDidMount` and `componentWillMount` lifecycle methods.

Comment: thanks for your help, you made my understanding of this topic easier. The literature in that tutorial just confused me, thanks for setting things straight.